# How to use Mathematica with Slurm?

Tags: parallelization, high-performance-clusters

We have a cluster that uses [Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com). On each node we have put a license that allows for 128 computation kernels (we have a Mathematica for Sites License). How can we run Mathematica on more than one node using Slurm?

Comment: SLURM is mentioned by name in this article: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/27867